# Связь таблицы с двумя другими в зависимости от состояния флага

Tags: sql

Не смог сформулировать коротко и ясно, попробую проилюстлрировать примером.

Есть таблица А

```
Столбец А1 | Столбец А2 | Флаг | Указатель
```

Таблица В

```
Указатель | Столбец В1 | Столбец В2
```

Таблица С

```
Указатель | Столбец С1
```

Нужно, в зависимости от значения флага из таблицы А (0 или 1, к примеру), соединять с ней либо таблицу В, либо таблицу С, чтобы в результате было так:

```
Столбец А1 | Столбец А2 | Флаг | Указатель | Столбец В1 | Столбец В2 
    А11    |     А21    |  0   |    58     |     В14    |    В25 
    А12    |     А22    |  0   |    92     |     В17    |    В29
```

Либо так:

```
Столбец А1 | Столбец А2 | Флаг | Указатель | Столбец С1
    А15    |     А26    |  1   |    82     |    С1
    А18    |     А28    |  1   |    94     |    С1
```

Можно ли это как-то реализовать за один запрос?

Comment: А если значение флага для разных строк разное, какой результат вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: Подсказка:

    select a, b, c 
    union all
    select d, e, null

Answer (score 1):

Можно объединить все три таблицы при помощи `LEFT JOIN`, а в `SELECT` выводить результат в зависимости от того, какое значение принимает флаг

```
SELECT
  A.A1 AS A1,
  A.A2 AS A2,
  A.ext_id AS ext_id,
  A.flag AS flag,
  (CASE A.flag WHEN 0 THEN B.B1 WHEN 1 THEN A.A1 END) AS par1,
  (CASE A.flag WHEN 0 THEN B.B2 WHEN 1 THEN NULL END) AS par2
FROM
  A
LEFT JOIN
  B
ON
  A.ext_id = B.id
LEFT JOIN
  C
ON
  A.ext_id = C.id
```